# Reload activity on homebutton click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I use the below shown code to get home button click and to reload activity. If i click home button from my app, the `Activity` successfully reloads with a delay of 1 to 2 seconds.

but after clicking home button if i open any other application ,the activity reloading wont work.

```
    @Override
    protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    startActivity(intent);


    super.onUserLeaveHint();

    }
```

Please help me to solve the issue.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why would you want to reload the activity if the user leaves your app? If you want to run some process in the background you should use a Service (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html).

Comment: @Prag's .. I am building a lock application. So the user must stay in the app till the app gets an authentication code.Actually I need to disable the home button. 'Disabling home button in ICS and above is the actual motive when my lock app is running'

Comment: @Minto Did you get to know why the activity reload won't work, when another app is opened?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to reload Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```